# Thymeleaf does not see reference from Controller

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, thymeleaf

I'm trying to show all Customers from my local database(PostgreSQL) on the html page using Thymeleaf. My project is using Spring Boot.

Connection and getting data from database is not the point of this question(or is it?). The point is that thymeleaf does not see model that i passed through controller.

homePage.html

```
!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Opera</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Opera home page'" />

<ul th:each="customer : ${customers}">
<li>
    <span th:text="${customers.getFirstName}">Name</span>
    <span th:text="${customers.getLastName}">Surname</span>
    <span th:text="${customers.getPhone}">Phone</span>
    <span th:text="${customers.getEmail}">e-mail</span>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

HomePageController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomePageController {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public HomePageController(CustomerRepository customerRepository){
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(Model model) {
        List<Customer> customers = Lists.newArrayList(customerRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "homePage";
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull private String firstName;
    @NotNull private String lastName;
    @NotNull private String phoneNumber;
    @NotNull private String email;

    protected Customer(){}

    public Customer(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String email){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(
            "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s', phoneNumber='%s', emailr='%s']",this.getId(),
            firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email);
    }
}
```

Screenshot from html file showing problem:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob4Dl.jpg)

Edit: some english corrections :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use getter in the template. Do like this:

```
<span th:text="${customer.firstName}">Name</span>
```

Sorry you also have to remove the s

Comment: I changed it to customer.firstName etc  but thymeleaf seems to not recognize customers list at all so the for each loop wont even start

Comment: Nvm, thats was the case :) Its working but customers is still highlighted. Its IntelliJ bug apparently. Thanks!